# Could not load type 'xxx`1' from assembly from assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, structuremap

I know sometimes (here lately) I've been asking more questions than I answer and for that I apologize, but I have yet another question.

Thanks to Kev Ritchie my last issue has been resolved, but that just lead me to another error. When I try debugging (**Debug** > **Start Debugging** then I am promptly greeted with this error:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not
>   load type
>   'GodsCreationTaxidermy.Data.GenericRepository`1'
>   from assembly 'GodsCreationTaxidermy,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.

This is the code that the view **Views** > **Index**

```
[CanonicalUrlAttribute("Index")]
public virtual ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = image.Find(x => x.is_featured.Value);
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

And here's a screenshot of the error (I tried several ideas from this site already and none have worked thus far) [image]. The line it is highlighting is where I initialize StructureMap, this line

```
 x.ForRequestedType(typeof(IRepository<>))
```

Here's the entire initialize code in the Gobal.asax

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
    {
        x.ForRequestedType<IUnitOfWorkFactory>()
            .TheDefaultIsConcreteType<EFUnitOfWorkFactory>()
            .CacheBy(InstanceScope.HybridHttpSession);

        x.ForRequestedType(typeof(IRepository<>))
            .CacheBy(InstanceScope.HybridHttpSession)
            .TheDefaultIsConcreteType(typeof(GenericRepository<>));
    });
```

Anyone got any ideas, the last thing I tried was to empty everything from the bin folder, clean the solution then rebuild it as stated in [this thread](http://rlm.cc/jaWhfH) from here on SO. This project used to work (not completed but what was completed worked like a charm), all I did was move GenericRepository to GodsCreationTaxidermy.Data from GodsCreationTaxidermy.Data.Repository, not sure how that could have broke this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been resolved. The default Namespace and Assembly had different names. Once I made their names the same the error has disappeared